# How to group rows and select latest date to display in a data table

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, dataview

What are some ways I can sort the data table in the first image to look like it does in the second?

When the values of dosage, drug, and patient are the same for two or more rows, I want to merge them and use the newest date.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you querying these from a database? If so, what is your DBMS?

Comment: do it in your sql query, this is the correct way.

Comment: I would recommend in the future to take the time to actually create tables with your data rather than paste images. It makes it harder for someone to recreate your issue in an SQL Fiddle to test with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going to deep into actual C# code, I would recommend not focusing on how to manipulate the data table, but instead writing the proper query to get the information you want.

You can use a `GROUP BY` clause to group by dosage, drug, and patient, and use `MAX()` in your select statement to get the latest date for that group. You can also sort by the date in ascending order to match the layout you have. Try this:

```
SELECT dosage, drug, patient, MAX(date) AS date
FROM myTable
GROUP BY dosage, drug, patient
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1057/1) example for you.

Comment: Thanks! didn't know alot of SQL commands, but it seems it is lot easier to do manipulation in SQL than C#.

Comment: @Jliu1729 it definitely is easier, in my opinion. If you can write the proper query, all you have to do is loop through your result set and add into the table.